# Как авторизоваться на YoBit в приложении на C#?

Tags: c#

Пробую следующим образом:

```csharp
public string youbitMoney()
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sign);
    art = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sign);
    
    HMACSHA512 ds = new HMACSHA512(art);
                
    var req = new HttpRequest();
    req.AddHeader("Key", apiKey);
    req.AddHeader("Sign", ds.ToString());
    
    var urlParams = new RequestParams();
    urlParams["nonce"] = 1;
    
    string send = req.Post(url, urlParams).ToString();
    
    var money = JObject.Parse(send);
    JToken mk = money["usdt_btc"];
    
    return mk.ToString();
}
```

Приходит такой ответ:

```json
{
    "success": 0,
    "error": "invalid key, sign, method or nonce"
}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Уважаемый автор, расскажите, пожалуйста, что такое YoBit, дайте немного информации по его API или хотя бы дайте ссылку на статью, которая помогла Вам написать этот код. Мы ведь не можем знать API всех на свете сервисов.

Comment: И еще беглое гугление показало, что, возможно, Вам поможет эта библиотека: https://github.com/iHold/YobitApiClient

Comment: Что за приложение? ASP.NET, UWP?

Comment: приложение WinForms

Comment: Что такое `new HttpRequest()`, это из какого неймспейса или библиотеки взято? Если [отсюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.8), то я не совсем понимаю, что происходит.

Comment: @aepot, вряд ли оттуда, это первое предположение было, но у того HttpRequest  совсем другой интерфейс. Я вот думаю, может быть это Xamarin и этот класс из Anroid SDK... Автор, подскажите, интересно же, оказывается не только мне.